# HTML span tag content and attribute preg_match regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

Does anyone have a fix for the following;

I'm taking the following string:

```
<span id="tmpl_main_lblWord" class="randomWord">kid</span>
```

and using the following preg_match / regex rule;

```
preg_match("'/(<span id=.* class=.*>)(.*)(<\/span>)/'si", $buffer, $match);
```

But its returning with an empty array any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I would strongly advise against using regex to try and get values from HTML. I would use an HTML parser. See this question: [Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

If you insist though... you seem to have two sets of nested quotes. I would remove the inner single quotes. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following example uses [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHtml('<span id="tmpl_main_lblWord" class="randomWord">kid</span>');
$el = $doc->getElementById('tmpl_main_lblWord');
echo 'Inner text is: ' . $el->textContent;
```